# Delete the last part of the menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I am not able to delete the last part of the menu in Wordpress site of my client. 
The original line of code is this:

```
ul # top-menu li {
    padding-left: 19px; 
    background: url (images / menu-bg.png) no-repeat right 3px;
}
```

which CSS code should I use?

Comment: Please explain and write code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you haven't included any proper code and the website link which you've included opens up a coming soon page, I am not quite sure what you're referring to but from what I understand, you'd like to remove the last `<li>` present inside your menu. If yes, you can do that by setting the `display` property of the last `<li>` to `none` using the `last-child` psuedo-selector like this:

```
ul#top-menu li:last-child {
     display: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you've clarified that you want to remove the background image from the last `<li>`, you may use this CSS:

```
ul#top-menu li:last-child {
     background: none;
}
```

If you want a solution which would work for older versions of IE then what you can do is that you can define a `class` for the last menu item by logging into your Wordpress Dashboard, navigating to Appearance>Menus, clicking on the `screen options` button in the top-right corner and placing a check on `CSS classes`. Next, scroll down, click to open the last menu item and type the `class-name` inside the `CSS Classes (optional)` input field. After saving the menu, you can set the `background` to `none` for the last menu item by targeting the CSS class which you set for it, like this (I've assumed the `class-name` of the last menu item to be `last-menu-item`):

```
ul#top-menu li.last-menu-item {
     background: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Fahad, 

I think we are close to solving. 

This code also removed the word Contact. I want to remove only the last image menu-bg.png 

What do you suggest?

Comment: @AlexVilela Please check my updated answer above, this should work perfectly.

Comment: It worked! 

You can not imagine how happy I am now. 

Thank Fahad!

Comment: @alexvilela I am glad it worked. Please mark my answer as correct so that users can know your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: With pleasure. To do it? It's the first time I participate.

Comment: @alexvilela There would be an outline of a tick-mark right next to my answer above, you will simply need to click on that to accept my answer. Moreover, going through this link will be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Just one more question. How can I centralize that part image?

Comment: How can I centralize now?

Comment: You can try using this CSS: `ul#top-menu li { background-position: center; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Its not smart to remove it like Fahad says, you can just remove the links in the menu.

Log in on the admin account of the site and go to:

From the 'Appearance' menu on the left-hand side of the Dashboard, select the 'Menus' option to bring up the Menu Editor.

Select the menu where the link is in, and remove it from that list. Save it, and you're done...

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ul#top-menu li:last-child 
{
    background: none;
}
```

This will remove the background image from the last menu item (in your case it will remove the line on the right).

EDIT: As ninja has pointed out, using `last-child` won't work on some versions of IE, so this method should work if you want to support them:

```
ul#top-menu > li + li + li + li + li + li + li + li 
{
    background: none;
}
```

This will remove the background from the 8th menu item (each li is referring to a menu item), you will need to remember to update this is you add/remove an items from the menu.

Comment: Worth noting that :last-child pseudo-selector isn't supported in IE8, so if you need IE8-support you would have to do a javascript fallback for the same effect

Comment: @ninja, thanks for that reminder. I have edited my answer, but you don't really need to use a javascript fallback.